# Dialing a phone number with * characters

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-intent

Fails on my android app, all normal numbers work well.

I found that apple explicitly ban dialing such numbers for fear of call forwarding tricks, but I cant find a documented reason dor this to fail on Android SDK

can you point me out to a document with the reason ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Probably you mean dialing an USSD code. If it's so - then it's long and intriguing story as it's still among android feature requests (take a look at [Feature Request: Add USSD API support](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1285)).

As far as I know the only workaround using Uri.encode exists as a solution for this:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(“tel:” + Uri.encode(strPhoneNumber))));
```

and you also need these permissions in manifest file:

```
android.permission.CALL_PHONE
android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED 
android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE
```

Comment: What is your code which is failing? Do you use Uri.parse anyway?

Comment: I am using geturl via appcelerator mobile

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too, and the I think the last answer is true but i suggest you to use this code to Dial a number like *8373

```
String star = Uri.encode("*");
        String Hash = Uri.encode("#"); // if you want use # to add in your number! :)
        Intent call = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        Charge.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + star +"8373"));
        startActivity(Charge);
```